# docker push to gcr.io fails with "denied: Token exchange failed for project"

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've discovered a flow that works through GCP console but not through the `gcloud` CLI.

### Minimal Repro

The following bash snippet creates a fresh GCP project and attempts to push an image to gcr.io, but fails with "access denied" even though the user is project owner:

```
gcloud auth login

PROJECT_ID="example-project-20181120"
gcloud projects create "$PROJECT_ID" --set-as-default
gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com
gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet

mkdir ~/docker-source && cd ~/docker-source
git clone https://github.com/mtlynch/docker-flask-upload-demo.git .

LOCAL_IMAGE_NAME="flask-demo-app"
GCR_IMAGE_PATH="gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/flask-demo-app"
docker build --tag "$LOCAL_IMAGE_NAME" .
docker tag "$LOCAL_IMAGE_NAME" "$GCR_IMAGE_PATH"
docker push "$GCR_IMAGE_PATH"
```

**Result**

```
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/example-project-20181120/flask-demo-app]
02205dbcdc63: Preparing
06ade19a43a0: Preparing
38d9ac54a7b9: Preparing
f83363c693c0: Preparing
b0d071df1063: Preparing
90d1009ce6fe: Waiting
denied: Token exchange failed for project 'example-project-20181120'. Access denied.
```

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest version of gcloud [225.0.0, as of this writing](https://gist.github.com/mtlynch/40ebf89e39890b71d738ee4fcf1c3a17#file-gistfile1-txt). The account I auth'ed with [has role `roles/owner`](https://gist.github.com/mtlynch/40ebf89e39890b71d738ee4fcf1c3a17#file-gistfile2-txt).

## Inconsistency with GCP Console

I notice that if I follow the same flow through GCP Console, I can `docker push` successfully:

1. Create a new GCP project via GCP Console
2. Create a service account with `roles/owner` via GCP Console
3. Download JSON key for service account
4. Enable container registry API via GCP Console
5. `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json`
6. `gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID`
7. `gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet`
8. `docker tag "$LOCAL_IMAGE_NAME" "$GCR_IMAGE_PATH" && docker push "$GCR_IMAGE_PATH"`

**Result**: Works as expected. Successfully pushes docker image to gcr.io.

## Other attempts

I also tried using `gcloud auth login` as my @gmail.com account, then using that account to create a service account with gcloud, but that gets the same `denied` error:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME=test-service-account
gcloud iam service-accounts create "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME"
KEY_FILE="${HOME}/key.json"
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create "$KEY_FILE" \
  --iam-account "${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding "$PROJECT_ID" \
  --member "serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role roles/owner
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="${HOME}/key.json"

docker push "$GCR_IMAGE_PATH"
```

**Result**: `denied: Token exchange failed for project 'example-project-20181120'. Access denied.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same error using bash snippet you provided, however it successfully built the ‘flask-demo-app’ container registry image for me. I used below steps to reproduce the issue:

Step 1: Use account which have ‘role: roles/owner’ and ‘role: roles/editor’

Step 2: Created bash script using your given snippet

Step 3: Added  ‘gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file skey.json’ in script to authenticate the account

Step 4: Run the bash script

Result : It created the ‘flask-demo-app’ container registry image

This leads me to believe that there might be an issue with your environment which is causing this error for you. To troubleshoot this you could try running your code on a different machine, a different network or even on the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/).

Comment: Thanks for investigating, Amit!

I can get it to work if I create a service account as well, but my expectation is that it should also work under the root account (my gmail.com root account for GCP). In your repro, you created a separate service account. Can you do it under your root gmail account?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. Yes,I have tried with my root account which have the same permissions and it worked as well.

Comment: Not sure what's going on then. I just tried again with gcloud 226 and got the same `Access denied` result with both the root account and the service account I created with gcloud.

Comment: Based on the information given, it would appropriate to investigate this further. If you would like a deeper look into this issue, it would be my recommendation to create a private issue on [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Using Issue tracker will allow Google support agents to investigate the details of your Google Cloud Platform environment and determine whether this is intended behaviour or not for the specified product.

Answer (score 0):

In my case project IAM permission was the issue. Make sure proper permission given and also cloud resource/container registry API enabled.
[GCP Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#iam)